# how to get a single parameter from Resultset into String array

Tags: java, arrays, resultset

Code for `getDbTable()` is:

```
public String[][] getDbTable(String vs_name)
{
    int i = 0;
    String a[][] = new String[3600][16];
    System.out.println("datetime is" +d);
    System.out.println("datetime is" +currentDate);
    try
    {
         con = getConnection();


         String sql = "exec vcs_gauge @gauge_name=?,@first_rec_time=?,@last_rec_time=?";
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
         System.out.println("date is "+df.format(currentDate));
         clstmt = con.prepareCall(sql); 
         clstmt.setString(1,"vs1_bag");

        clstmt.setString(2, "2014-09-01 10:00:00");
        clstmt.setString(3, "2014-09-01 11:00:00");

          clstmt.execute();
          rs = clstmt.getResultSet();



        while (rs.next())
        {
            for(int j=0; j<16; j++)
            {
                    a[i][j] = rs.getString(j+1);

            }

            i++;
        }

    }

    catch( Exception e )
    {
        System.out.println("\nException in Display Bean in getDbTable(String code):"+e);
    }
    finally
    {

        //closeConnection();
    }
    return a; 
}
```

How to get a single parameter from `ResultSet` into `String` type of array. I want to retrieve "logtime" which is my first column in the table and store it into String Array. I tried the following code:

```
public String[] getcahrttime() throws SQLException
{   
    getConnection();
    getDbTable(vs_name);
    String[] timeStr = null;
    while(rs.next()){
        char[] time= rs.getString("logtime").toCharArray();
        timeStr = new String[time.length];
        for (int i=0,len=time.length; i<len; i++){
            timeStr[i] = String.valueOf(time[i]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("time is"+timeStr);
    return timeStr;
}
```

where `getConnection` establishes the connection and `getDbTable(vs_name)` returns the table with all columns in it.

When I run the above code then `timestr` is getting `null` value. How to fix the problem.

Comment: What is `rs` / `vs_name`, what's the code in `getConnection` and `getDbTable`?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want here?  If there are three rows in the database, do you want the result to be a three-element array, with each element being the value of one row?  Your current approach looks... different.

Comment: Try to use a debugger and step through your code. If timeStr is NULL it's most likely due to something going wrong before that assignment. Using your debugger output traces (System.out.println(yourVariable)) check out if all the other values match your expectations.

Comment: (Also, are you sure that a column called `"logtime"` is a String?  If it's a date/time type, you really *really* ought to represent it as a date/time type in Java.  Passing everything around as Strings is poor design.)

Comment: @RC.rs is the Resulset and vs_name is a String variable which i'm passing as a argument in getDbTable()method to pass dynamic values in argument in jsp page.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle logtime is of datetime type but I need to use it as String type as I'am using chartdirector where I have to pass this logtime column values along the x-axis in the chart.I have seen examples where it used only String type values along the x-axis,so i did it.help me to fix the problem.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle I just want that all the values of logtime column be stored into an array of String type.In my sql database i have 3600 rows,therefore logtime has 3600 values.

Comment: I think you need to use the result from `getDbTable`, this method crafts some 2-D array that you don't use. Also once `ResultSet#next()` return false, any new call on the same `ResultSet` to next **will return false**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK - your first problem is that *for each row*, you're resetting the `timeStr` variable and throwing away everything you read from earlier rows.  That obviously can't work.  Instead, we need to initialise the array once, and then only add to it (exactly one value for each row found).

The problem with this, is that arrays need to be initialised with a specific size - and we don't know ahead of time how many rows there will be.  One way of dealing with this would be to run a `count(*)` query first, and then initialise your array to that size.  Or, specific `ResultSet` implementations might be able to tell you the size of the set, though this is not guaranteed.

But the easiest way is simply to use a `List` instead of an array, as these can be resized dynamically.  I find them much easier to work with, so would pass it around as a `List` right up to the point it needs to be converted - but here I'll convert it to an array for the sake of demonstration.

Asides from that it's easy - there's no need to mess with character arrays:

```
public String[] getChartTime() throws SQLException
{
    // ...
    // Earlier lines as before, let's start from the variable
    final List<String> timeStr = new ArrayList<>();
    while(rs.next()) {
        // Just get the value of the column, and add it to the list
        timeStr.add(rs.getString("logtime"));
    }

    // I would return the list here, but let's convert it to an array
    return timeStr.toArray(new String[timeStr.size()]);
}
```

Comment: Doyle when I run my code then timestr is showing as timestr is [].No values are shown in it.

Comment: @Andezej Doyle How to print timeStr array ,so that i can check whether correct values are present in timestr array or not.

Comment: You want to call `Arrays.toString(timeStr)`, rather than letting `timeStr` be implicitly converted to a String via its own `toString()` method.  However, I would encourage you to learn how to use a debugger, if you want to inspect variables in order to validate your code.  Println simply isn't an option for non-trivial cases.

Comment: And if there are no values in the result, then (based on the code above) `rs` **must** have returned no rows.  Again - fire up a debugger and see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I think your loop is messed up. At the moment the thing does the following:

- take one row of your result set.
- take the column "logtime" from that row
- create a string array that contains as many strings as time has
  characters (why that?!?)
- finally you convert every character of time
  (the char array) into an individual string and copy that string to a
  specific element in your string array since you declare everything in
  the loop, all the info will be gone for the next iteration of the
  loop

I'd suggest you think about your loop structure again. Try using a debugger it will show you the problem